# Assigning value from table to pandas dataframe if contains substring

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a system in which I assign a merchant name to transactions. The way to assign the name is by looking up if specific substring exists in the transaction concept. e.g. if `Amzn` in `Compra Amzn Mktp Es*asdfasdgas, Luxembourg`, I want it to assign `Amazon`. I created a CSV table `merchants.csv` which contains all abbreviations and names.

| abr | name |
| --- | --- |
| amz | Amazon |
| uber *Eats | UberEats |
| Orange | Orange |
| etc. | etc. |

I have only found a solution to iterate through the two dfs and assign value (code below), but it feels very awkward and I feel there is a better solution.
Could you please suggest?

```
data = {'Date': ['31/07/2023', '31/07/2023', '30/07/2023', '29/07/2023'], 
        'Concept': ['Compra Uber *eats, Help.uber.com', 'Compra Amzn Mktp Es*k46q26ow5, Luxembourg', 'Compra Uber *eats, Help.uber.com', 'Recibo Orange Espagne S.a.u-orange Espagne Sa Nº'], 
        'Amount':[-10,-12,-15,-22]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_merch = pd.read_csv(r'C:\new\acct\mercants.csv')

for n, row in df.iterrows():
    for abr in df_merch['abr']:
        if abr in row['Concept']:
            df.loc[n,'Merchant'] = df_merch.loc[df_merch['abr']==abr].iloc[0]['name']
            break
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of `df` (`MovimientosCuenta.xlsx`)

Comment: Use `.map` or `.apply` instead of `.iterrows`. The latter is only for cases where parallel execution is impossible because you need the results from before. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#iteration

Comment: @mozway adjusted the code to include data for df.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can craft a regex for [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and combine it with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
import re

df_merch['abr'] = df_merch['abr'].str.casefold()

pat = '(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(df_merch['abr'],
                                              key=len, reverse=True)))
# '(uber\\ \\*Eats|Orange|etc\\.|amz)'

df['Merchant'] = (df['Concept'].str.casefold()
                  .str.extract(pat, expand=False)
                  .map(df_merch.set_index('abr')['name'])
                 )
```

Output:

```
         Date                                           Concept  Amount  Merchant
0  31/07/2023                  Compra Uber *eats, Help.uber.com     -10  UberEats
1  31/07/2023         Compra Amzn Mktp Es*k46q26ow5, Luxembourg     -12    Amazon
2  30/07/2023                  Compra Uber *eats, Help.uber.com     -15  UberEats
3  29/07/2023  Recibo Orange Espagne S.a.u-orange Espagne Sa Nº     -22    Orange
```